# Converting timestamps to POSIXct format returns double

Tags: r, posixct

I want to convert a data frame to a `ltraj` list using the R package `adehabitatLT`, and for doing so I must convert timestamps to `POSIXct` format. I am writing the following code:

```
martin_df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(martin_df$timestamp,
                                      format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="GTM")
```

and throws no error. But then when I ask for:

```
typeof(martin_df$timestamp)
```

it tells me is double.

```
martin.ltraj <- as.ltraj(martin_df, typeII = TRUE)
```

> Error in as.ltraj(martin_df, typeII = TRUE) : For objects of type II,
> date should be of class "POSIXct"

Does anyone know where the error is?

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of head of your data

Comment: Did you meant `tz = 'GMT'`

Comment: Instead of `typeof` you shoud check with `class` i.e. `class(martin_df$timestamp)`

Comment: Without showing your input data, it is not clear.   I am guessing that `as.ltraj(martin_df, date = martin_df$timestamp, typeII = TRUE, id = martin_df$id)` should work change the `martin_df$id` if the id column name is different